# Java : Count even values in a Binary Search Tree recursively

Tags: java, recursion, tree, count, binary-search-tree

I need to find out how many even values are contained in a binary tree.

this is my code.

```
private int countEven(BSTNode root){

if ((root == null)|| (root.value%2==1))
return 0;

return 1+ countEven(root.left) + countEven(root.right);


}
```

this i just coded as i do not have a way to test this out. I'm not able to test it out at the moment but need an answer so badly.
any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: why are you not able to test it? Can't you write a testcase?

Comment: What are you in class taking an exam ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an node with an odd value containing subnodes with even values, the subnodes will not be counted in your code. Small enhancement below.

```
private int countEven(BSTNode root){

  if (root == null)
    return 0;

  int val = (root.value%2==1) ? 0 : 1;

  return val + countEven(root.left) + countEven(root.right);


}
```

Comment: Hi Thank you very much. Thanks for helping to figure out what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int countEven(BSTNode root) {
   if (root == null)
      return 0;

   int n = countEven(root.left) + countEven(root.right);
   if(root.value % 2 == 0)
      return n + 1;
   else
      return n;
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow: where programmers will do your homework with no questions asked.

Comment: hm, I don't agree with the -1... The poster tried something himself which did not work. Now he has a better solution, so he will be able to compare and see what he did wrong. So he certainly will have learned something from it...

Comment: Yes, you could say that for every instance in which someone responds to a homework question with a fully-written solution.  The flip side is that they can just copy it and learn nothing except that they can come here to get their homework done for free.

Comment: I do not agree with -1 either, so +1 for you:)

Comment: No, the big difference with a normal homework question is that he tried something himself, instead of only posting the question.

Comment: and yes. I tried to code it with my brain without testing it out. I have a test tomorrow morning and I dont want to bother writing BST class and making up a tree to test this out. infact i knew there is nothing much missing from my code. so thumbs up to Fortega and ltay. there's still some good humans left in this world.